# Linked error/Makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker

I am sure this is stupid but i get this linker error
`undefined reference to insert_record` ,which is a function declared in Operations.hpp,implemented in Operations.cpp and used in main, and i can't find what is wrong in this makefile.
Maybe a pair of rested eyes can spot the problem.
It seems that operations isn't linked although the object is being created.

```
OBJS = main.o Operations.o CDR.o TBucketList.o RBucketList.o  DateTime.o HashTable.o
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wno-unused -pedantic  -c -g
LDFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wno-unused -pedantic  -g

werhaus: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o werhaus

main.o : CDR.hpp Operations.hpp HashTable.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp

Operations.o : Operations.hpp HashTable.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) Operations.cpp

TBucketList.o : TBucketList.hpp RBucketList.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) TBucketList.cpp

RBucketList.o : RBucketList.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) RBucketList.cpp

HashTable.o : HashTable.hpp TBucketList.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) HashTable.cpp

CDR.o : CDR.hpp DateTime.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) CDR.cpp

DateTime.o : DateTime.hpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) DateTime.cpp

    clean:
    \rm *.o  werhaus
```

Update:
main.cpp :

```
insert_record(originator_number, aCDR, destination_number, hashtable1, hashtable2, BucketSize);
```

Operations.hpp:

```
void insert_record(const char*, CDR*, const char*, const Hashtable*, const Hashtable*, int);
```

Operations.cpp:

```
void insert_record(const char* originator_number, CDR* aCDR, const char* destination_number, Hashtable* hashtable1, Hashtable* hashtable2, int Bsize)
```

All seem fine in main..

Comment: " i get this linker error" - what linker error?

Comment: sorry for my stupidness :D .Edited!

Comment: Off topic but... your makefile dependencies seem a bit odd.  For example you specify `HashTable.o`'s dependency on various headers but not its dependency on `HashTable.cpp` -- and likewise for the other files specified in `OBJS`.

Comment: I started only recently writing and using makefiles but i thought dependent .cpp files with the same name as the object were autodiscovered and treated as dependencies by make.I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an error in your `Makefile`. As @G.M. noted, the dependencies of `.o` to corresponding `.cpp` are missing, these need to be added.

It can be that `insert_record` declaration in `Operations.hpp` does not match the definition in `Operations.cpp` and you end up with two functions `insert_record`. Check that the function declaration and definitions match: same return type and argument types, both in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better use something like this:

```
NAME=   werhaus

CXX=          g++ # Use CXX for C++
CXXFLAGS=     -W -Wall -Wno-unused -pedantic -g
LDFLAGS=      -g # No need for warning flags at linking

SRC=    main.cpp          \
        Operations.cpp    \
        CDR.cpp           \
        TBucketList.cpp   \
        RBucketList.cpp   \
        DateTime.cpp      \
        HashTable.cpp

OBJS=   $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)

all:    $(NAME)

%.o:    %.cpp
        $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
        rm -f $(NAME)

re:     fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

This type of makefile will avoid you a lot of errors.

Also, you don't need to put hpp files as dependencies.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In `Operations.hpp` you have a declaration with signature:

```
void insert_record(
    const char*, CDR*, 
    const char*, 
    const Hashtable*, 
    const Hashtable*,
    int)
```

In `Operations.cpp` you *define* a function with the different signature:

```
void insert_record(
    const char* CDR*,
    const char*, 
    Hashtable*, 
    Hashtable*,
    int)
```

So the declaration in `Operations.hpp` is not in fact implemented in `Operations.cpp`
and is undefined.